# Fast Fourier Transform on Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, resampling

I would like some guidance on the proper way to compute a FFT on python for a real, non-periodic signal. I am relatively new to coding and signal analysis, so this post will contain questions relatives to both domains.

To give some context, here is a graphical representation of my signal (time domain):

[image]

and this is the data I am working from:

```
t_norm  acc_norm
1   0.000000  0.000000
2   0.031918  2.336610
3   0.063340  1.817758
4   0.095058  0.544868
5   0.126293 -0.953833
6   0.157302  0.217959
7   0.188844 -1.331151
8   0.219892 -1.548037
9   0.251234  2.288458
10  0.282859  2.837413
11  0.314361  1.835081
12  0.345838  1.659622
13  0.376913  1.309823
14  0.408362  1.035765
15  0.439503  0.771576
16  0.470980  1.235591
17  0.502364  2.456847
18  0.533518  1.668552
19  0.564633  1.076637
20  0.595747  1.377580
21  0.626756  0.673881
22  0.658192  0.529822
23  0.689240  0.483709
24  0.720207  1.354278
25  0.751281  2.072109
26  0.782463  1.027122
27  0.813699  0.333459
28  0.844841  0.406036
29  0.875902  0.401840
30  0.906883  0.044780
31  0.937957  0.557944
32  0.968992  1.962894
33  1.000000  1.446186
```

Note that the device used to record the signal use a variable rate sampling with cross detection to capture data points. It limits (down samples) this to a maximum of 50 points per seconde (50Hz). I have made an histogram to show the distribution of the time intervals between measurements of all my datas :

[image]

METHODOLOGICAL QUESTIONS:

1. In regards to the overall shape of my signal (Fig 1), should I detrend it before doing the FFT (I am only interested in the high frequencies) ?
2. Does the FFT necessarily require to resample the datas if the rate of sampling is not uniform, even if the distribution of the time intervals between measurements is not really spread out (Fig 2) ?

TECHNICAL QUESTIONS (PYTHON):

1. All the examples I have seen on internet on how to compute a FFT works from a synthetic signals (directly made in python). I have tried to reproduce the methodology used and adapt it to fit for my signal derived from 'real world' data. The first steps seems to be to calculate some characteristics of the signal, and then to compute the FFT.

   ## Signal characteristics

   spl_nbr =    # number of sample of the signal

   d_fs =       # sampling frequency, hertz

   i_ns = (2*d_fs)

   d_time = np.linspace(0, (i_ns-1), i_ns)/d_fs # Time series, seconds

   d_f_sig =    # signal freqeuncy, hertz

   d_sig =      # signal itself

   ## Compute the FFT

   cx_y = rfft(d_sig)/float(i_ns/2.)

   d_ws = rfftfreq(i_ns,1./d_fs)

Therefore, I would like to know how to calculate each elements from my datas. I know I can use `.count()` function to calculate the number of sample of the signal, but that is pretty much all I can do for now. I am especially wondering on how I should pass the signal information (d_sig) to python.

Thank you in advance for your contributions, and feel free to comment on things that I could be missing in my approach !

Comment: See [Python Fourier Transform Helper Library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5329670/Python-Fourier-Transform-Helper-Library)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) You need to take some time and do your own research first. You should get decent answers if you google *"How to calculate ___"*, replacing `___` with the quantities you want to find. Since you're already using numpy, did you read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html) on numpy's fft capabilities.